# Test if its "success" or "fail" or "cancel" after the sign using DocuSign

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

i'm integrating docusign ,and i'm able to sign successfully a document, i want to be able to tell if the person signed the document  successfully or it's was a failure.

i have two function succes and failure that i need to know which one to call after the person procede to sign the assigned document.

How can i procced to test which function to call depending on the return after the person signed the document.

thanks in advance.

```
 public function send()

    {   
        $this->args = $this->getTemplateArgs();
       
        $args = $this->args;
       
        $envelope_args = $args["envelope_args"];
        
        
        # Create the envelope request object
        $envelope_definition = $this->makeEnvelopeFileObject($args["envelope_args"]);
        
        $apiClient = new ApiClient();
               
        $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath(config('app.auth_server')); 
        try{
            $accessToken = $this->getToken($apiClient);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return back()->withError($th->getMessage())->withInput();
        }
        
        
        
        $userInfo = $apiClient->getUserInfo($accessToken);
        $accountInfo = $userInfo[0]->getAccounts();
        $apiClient->getConfig()->setHost($accountInfo[0]->getBaseUri() . config('app.sufix'));  
        
        $apiClient->getConfig()->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
        
        
        $envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
        $results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelope_definition);
        
        $envelope_id = $results->getEnvelopeId();
        # Create the Recipient View request object
        $authentication_method = 'None'; # How is this application authenticating
        # the signer? See the `authenticationMethod' definition
        # https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient
        $recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest([
        'authentication_method' => $authentication_method,
        'client_user_id' => '1000',
        'recipient_id' => '1',
        'return_url' => $envelope_args['ds_return_url'],
        'user_name' => 'unknown', 'email' =>'unknown@gmail.com'
        ]);
        # Obtain the recipient_view_url for the signing ceremony
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        $results = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelope_id,
        $recipient_view_request);
       
        //return ['envelope_id' => $envelopeApi, 'redirect_url' => $results['url']];
       
        return Redirect::to($results['url']);
       

private function getTemplateArgs()
    {   
        $apiClient = new ApiClient();
       
        $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath(config('app.auth_server')); 
        
            $accessToken = $this->getToken($apiClient);
        

        $args = [
            'account_id' => config('app.client'),
            'base_path' => "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi",
            'ds_access_token' => $this->getToken($apiClient),
            'envelope_args' => [
                    'signer_client_id' => $this->signer_client_id,
                    
                    'ds_return_url' => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contract"
                ]
                
        ];
           
        return $args;
    }
          
    }

   public function success(Request $request){
        /// suppose to be called after the person signed the document successfully 
    }

    public function failure (Request $request){
       /// suppose to be called when the person doesnt procede to signe the document successfully
    }
```

my Route the one that i create for the test :

```
Route::get('/contract',[docusign::class,'index']);
Route::post('/contract',[docusign::class,'send']);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use a webhook, which we call [DocuSign Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/).

You can configure a [global Connect configuration](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-add-custom-connect-configuration-programmatically) so that every envelope sent from this account will result in an event notification for the webhook that you use.

Recommend you use a cloud URL from Azure or AWS etc. to avoid issues with firewall etc.

You can also make the [request on a specific envelope](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-a-connect-webhook-to-your-envelopes) so that only specific envelopes trigger the event, not every envelope on your account.

Comment: thanks for the reply, with docusign connect can i get the event notification result and use it as a test in my implementation code ?

Comment: if you mean if you can test DocuSign Connect - sure. In the development environment (also called "demo") you can do whatever you want, how many times you want - it's all free.

Comment: If you mean to test the event without setting up a listener, I would suggest you use a site like webook.site

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcTaBKf_c50

Comment: i'm very sorry but i didn't understand :  with the webhook.site can i get the status of an envelop in my controller so i can  test on that value?.  exemple : after a person signed successfully  the document i want to perform some action in my application so i will be calling a specific function  in my controller depending on the status of the envelope.                                                                                            
thank you so much for your help

Comment: no, the webhook site is just for testing purposes

Comment: To get the value into your controller, your code must be on a public website accessible on the internet. DocuSign cannot post webhooks to localhost on your laptop

Comment: thank you so much, can you please enlighten me with some solutions or a hint that i work on , i tried to search but didn't find some helpful solutions ?                                               Have a nice day/week and thank you again.

Comment: https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-worker-aws

Comment: This is code to set up a Connect listener on AWS